# Movies App with Vue 3 and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have made a Movies App with **Vue 3**, **TypeScript** and **The Movie Database (TMDB) API**. For aesthetics, I rely on Bootstrap 5.

[image]

In `src\App.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <TopBar />
  <router-view />
  <AppFooter />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  // Import components
  import TopBar from './components/TopBar.vue';
  import AppFooter from './components/AppFooter.vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    // Register components
    components: {
      TopBar,
      AppFooter
    }
  });
</script>

<style lang="scss">

  .app-logo {
    max-height: 25px;
    width: auto;
  }

  // Layout
  #app {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
```

The Navbar (`src\components\TopBar.vue`):

```
<template>
   <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md shadow-sm">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <router-link class="navbar-brand" to="/">
          <img src="../assets/logo.png" class="app-logo" alt="App Logo">
        </router-link>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mainNavigation" aria-controls="mainNavigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavigation">
          <ul class="navbar-nav pe-md-1 navbar-expand-md">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link class="nav-link" :class="$route.name == 'home' ? 'active':''" to="/">Now Playing</router-link>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <router-link class="nav-link" :class="$route.name == 'top_rated' ? 'active':''" to="/top-rated">Top Rated</router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          
          <form ref="searchForm" class="search_form w-100 mx-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input v-on:keyup="debounceMovieSearch" v-model="searchTerm" class="form-control search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search movies...">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn" type="button">
                  <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'search']" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div v-if="isSearch" @click="isSearch = false" class="search-results shadow-sm">
              <div v-if="this.movies.length">
                <router-link v-for="movie in movies.slice(0, 10)" :key="movie.id" :to="`/movie/${movie.id}`">
                  <SearchItem :movie="movie" />
                </router-link>
              </div>

              <div v-else>
                <p class="m-0 p-2 text-center">No movies found for this search</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
  import axios from 'axios';
  import env from '../env';
  import SearchItem from './SearchItem.vue';

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'TopBar',

    components: {SearchItem},

    data: () => ({
        searchForm: ref(null),
        isSearch: false,
        searchTerm: '',
        timeOutInterval: 1000,
        movies: []
      }),

    mounted() {
      this.windowEvents();
    },

    methods: {
      windowEvents() {
        // Check for click outside the search form
        window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
          if (!(this.$refs.searchForm as HTMLFormElement).contains(event.target as Node|null)) {
              this.isSearch = false;
          }
        });
      },

      debounceMovieSearch() {
        setTimeout(this.doMovieSearch, this.timeOutInterval)
      },

      doMovieSearch() {
        if (this.searchTerm.length > 2) {
            this.isSearch = true;
            axios.get(`${env.api_url}/search/movie?api_key=${env.api_key}&query=${this.searchTerm}`).then(response => {
            this.movies = response.data.results;
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
      },
    }
    });
</script>
```

In the views directory I have the `HomeView.vue` that displays a list of movies, via the **MoviesList.vue** component.

In HomeView.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
    <MoviesList listType="now_playing" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
  import MoviesList from '../components/MoviesList.vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'HomeView',

    components: {
      MoviesList
    },

    data: () => ({
      pageTitle: "Now Playing"
    })
  });
</script>
```

In MoviesList.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="row list">
    <div
      v-for="movie in movies"
      :key="movie.id"
      class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"
    >
      <MovieCard :movie="movie" :genres="genres" :showRating="true" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import env from "../env";
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MoviesList",
  components: { MovieCard },

  props: {
    listType: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    searchTerm: "",
    movies: [],
    genres: [],
  }),

  mounted() {
    this.listMovies();
    this.getGenres();
  },

  methods: {
    listMovies() {
      axios
        .get(
          `${env.api_url}/movie/${this.$props.listType}?api_key=${env.api_key}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
          this.movies = response.data.results;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },

    getGenres() {
      axios
        .get(`${env.api_url}/genre/movie/list?api_key=${env.api_key}`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.genres = response.data.genres;
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
[class*="col-"] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
</style>
```

The above component is **reusable**. I use it in the *Top Rated Movies* view, by *providing a different value* (from the one used on the Homepage view) for the `listType` prop:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="page-title">{{ pageTitle }}</h1>
    <MoviesList listType="top_rated" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import MoviesList from "../components/MoviesList.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TopRatedMoviesView",

  components: {
    MoviesList,
  },

  data: () => ({
    pageTitle: "Top Rated",
  })
});
</script>
```

In `src\components\MovieCard.vue` I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="movie card" @click="showDetails(movie.id)">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img
        :src="movieCardImage"
        :alt="movie.title"
        class="img-fluid"
      />
    </div>

    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card-title">{{ movie.title }}</h2>
      <p class="card-desc">{{ movie.overview }}</p>
      <span v-if="showRating" :title="`Score: ${movie.vote_average}`" class="score">{{ movie.vote_average}}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
      <p class="m-0 release">
        Release date: {{ dateTime(movie.release_date) }}
      </p>
      <p v-if="movieGenres" class="m-0 pt-1">
        <span class="genre" v-for="genre in movieGenres" :key="genre.id">
          {{ genre.name }}
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import moment from "moment";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MovieCard",

  props: {
    movie: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },

    genres: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
    },

    showRating: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  },

  data: () => ({
    genericCardImage: require("../assets/generic-card-image.png"),
  }),

  methods: {
    dateTime(value: any) {
      return moment(value).format("MMMM DD, YYYY");
    },

    showDetails(movie_id: any) {
      let movie_url = `/movie/${movie_id}`;
      window.open(movie_url, "_self");
    },
  },

  computed: {
    movieCardImage() {
      return !this.movie?.backdrop_path
        ? this.genericCardImage
        : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.backdrop_path}`;
    },

    movieGenres() {
      if (this.genres) {
        let genres = this.genres;
        return this.movie?.genre_ids
          .filter((genre_id: number) => genre_id in genres)
          .map((genre_id: number) => genres[genre_id])
          .filter((genre: { name: string }) => genre.name.length > 0);
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    },
  },
});
</script>
```

The app is significantly bigger: there is a *Movie details* view and an *Actor details* view, but instead of pasting it all here, I have put together **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-typescript-vue-cli-starter-68kyvk)**.

#### Questions

1. Is there any *code redundancy* (and ways to reduce it)?
2. Do you see any bad practices?
3. Any suggestions for code *optimization*, *modularization* and *reusability*?

Comment: My two cents are 1. use async vs thens, 2. should ```listMovies``` be ```getMovies```, it conflicts with ```getGenres``` as all they are doing is getting data and setting a property, 3. use event delegation for your ```window.addEventListener(```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is feedback from me.

- You can create a directive named composite for outside click.
- In the movieCard component => you can replace template logic with computed properties. like for the date `dateTime(movie.release_date)`
- Regarding typescript, don't overuse any. `movie_id` type is defined. It may be a string or number.
- In actorDetails, you used useRoute, use is a composable mostly used with composition API. In option API it is better to use `this.$route` directly.
- For reusability, you can use `mixin` which will handle all the API requests. You can figure out how it can be implemented.
- It can be a little awkward but if you use BaseCard with a name for actor and movie.
- You can register Axios as a global variable like `$api or $axios`.

Lastly, I think you need to move from Vue CLI to Vite. Use composition API instead of an option. It gives a lot of flexibility and reusability. Use tailwind (optional).

Comment: How do I "use Axios as a global variable like `$api` or `$axios`"?

Comment: import axiso from 'axios'

`const app = createApp(App);`
`app.config.globalProperties.$anyName = axios;`

Comment: And how do I use it?

Comment: in any vue component you can use `this.gobalVarName`.